# phpBB 500 Internal Server Error and no log outputs

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, phpbb, phpbb3

Good morning. I'm having a major issue with my phpBB installation.

I've transfered it to my computer to develop some plugins, so i'm running it on localhost, but, i've created a vHost with the exact same domain he is running online, so, i don't need to change the cookies configuration, and the database connection information is correct already.

Regard all of that, i'm getting a 500 internal server error, which displays no error on the screen nor the logs from apache and php.

I have error reporting on php as E_ALL also. What could be possible causing this, and what the solution might be?

Thanks in advance, Jorge Ferrari.

Comment: Check your actual logs. If you get a 500 error on screen, the actual error should be logged in your PHP error log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting nothing in the Apache / PHP error logs, then it's more likely to be a server configuration issue. I would suspect the problem is in a file called `.htaccess` in the phpBB folder. It can be used to customize the configuration in various ways, including things like setting up redirects and URL rewriting.

If the htaccess file tries to use an Apache feature which isn't available on the server, then it can generate a 500 error. You can test this by temporarily removing the file, and seeing if the website works at all (albeit possibly with some glitches).

If you've confirmed that it's the source of the problem, then ideally you'll need to enable the missing feature in the server's configuration (or possibly update the Apache installation). Alternatively, you can delete or comment-out the problematic bits of the htaccess file.

Either way, it sounds more like a webserver admin issue than programming. You might have more luck asking on the phpBB forums, or on a different Stack Exchange Q&A site (possibly Server Fault?).

Comment: What if i have no .htaccess?

Comment: Which was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have Rewrite module enabled?(most of the this will be the reason)

In httpd.conf and uncomment

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If you try to use module which is not loaded you will get 500 internal server error.

> Check your modules used in .htaccess file and check httpd.conf whether used modules are loaded